# Does Amazon provides customer phone through MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

We have developed a simple application to retrieve orders for one of our customer. Our customer is a register sellers on amazon market place.

We are able to fetch the orders. Along with the orders info our client is asking for phone number of the customer. Amazon order do have a field called 'Phone' but we are always getting NULL value.

Actually does amazon expose customer phone number? If yes, how we can get that info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to retrieve order information through Amazon MWS. If you use the XML OrderReport format, you'll receive both buyer and delivery phone number as part of the XML data:

```
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OrderReport>
        <AmazonOrderID>...</AmazonOrderID>
        ...
        <BillingData>
            ...
            <BuyerPhoneNumber>123-456 7890</BuyerPhoneNumber>
        </BillingData>
        <FulfillmentData>
            ...
            <Address>
                ...
                <PhoneNumber>123-456 7890</PhoneNumber>
            </Address>
        </FulfillmentData>
    </OrderReport>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today the `Phone` number is given in `ShippingAdress` when retrieving orders.